# Text Editor Control in Windows application in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, text-editor

I am using Windows application for development. In that i have functionality where there is a control in which user can type anything then edit them like bold, italic, underline, fore colour,back colour, insert image, edit size of font, change font type etc. Its like MS Word.

At present i am using RTF ( Rich text box) control for the same. but its to complex to use. Now i want other way to do that.

can any one suggest me any third party control which can full fill my requirement or any other way to do it? I am ready by third party control like MS Word functionality.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use controls from [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/Free/NetOffer/) or [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try controls from http://www.devexpress.com or http://www.telerik.com